# TabBar embed in Navigation Controller, Back button does not disappear

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have my views organized as below:

[image]

I try to add the Back button adding in each View Controller and also the TabViewController a combination and at some point even all of the commands:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem   = nil
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: false)
```

The best result I had was this:

[image]

where the back arrow disappeared and the buttoned seemed not to be functional however I cannot make the world BACK go away.

I also [add the project in my gitHub account](https://github.com/icaroNZ/NavAndTab/tree/NavAndTab/NavAndTab) in case someone is interested in give it a try.

The very little code and the application is setup in swift 1.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the use of all the commands you have mentioned

Comment: They are all trying to hide the back button

Comment: So you want to hide back button while keeping the navigation bar intact.

Comment: @Krishna Yes, the screen before this is the login screen so it should show the back button to this screen but it should work fine to the rest of the application

Comment: Do you want to keep the back button functionality on ViewController1 and ViewController2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88671/discussion-between-krishna-and-icaro).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

Remove navigation controller on viewController before TabBarController. This will remove back button from all the views that are presented after it.

Add navigation controller to the view controllers for both the tabs after TabBarController in storyboard.

Comment: that would be a mess in my code I have 5 view controllers and I call than all programatically sometime or another, I would prefer to fix the problem with the back button not been hide. But thanks